# Which of the following is NOT true of a variable character data type?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I Just started a SQL class and am new to the language. I need some help with this question. I believe the answer is It is more efficient in terms of disk storage but I am not sure. Please help and explain your answer so I can better myself and knowledge of the language.

Which of the following is NOT true of a variable character data type?
    It writes the exact number of characters the data contains to disk 
    It is more efficient in terms of disk storage
    It should be used sparingly.
    Conducting full text searches is easier.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know who asked the question but whoever it was, they need to learn how to write questions, since this one is nonsense! Of the choices given to be possible answers to the question: "Which of the following is NOT true of a variable character data type?", the option "It is more efficient in terms of disk storage" is nonsense since it would need to be considered more efficient than SOMETHING! Likewise the option "Conducting full text searches is easier." is also nonsense because the option does not state what it is supposed to be easier than.

Comment: Yeah I completely agree, that is why I have been having such a hard time determining the answer.